# GoRoutines and passing struct to original context

Tags: go, struct, goroutine

I have a configuration that defines a number of instances (SomeConfigItems) which have a thing() created for each of them.

That thing is a struct returned by an included package, which contains, among other things, a Price (float64) and a nested struct. The nested struct maintains a map of trades.

The problem is that I am able to loop through the thing.Streams.Trades and see all trades happening in real time from my main()'s for{} loop. I am not able to see an updated thing.Price even though it is set in the Handler on occasion.

I am having a hard time understanding how the nested structs can contain data but not Price. I feel as though I am missing something with scoping, goroutines, or possibly pointers for instantiation of new objects.

Any help would be appreciated, I will continue reading in the meantime. I've reduced the code to what seems relevant.

### main.go:

```
package main
import thing
var Things []thing.Handler

for _, name := range SomeConfigItems {
  handler := thing.New(name)
  Things = append(Things, handler)
}

for {
  for _, t := range Things {
    log.Info("Price: ", t.Price) // This is set to 0 every iteration, but I can actively data in thing.Streams.Trades
  }
}
```

### thing.go:

```
package thing
import streams

type Handler struct {
    Name  string
    Price   float64
    Streams streams.Streams
}

func New(name string) (h Handler, err error) {
    stream, err := streams.New(strings.ToLower(name))
    h = Handler{
        Name:  name,
        Price: "0.0"
        Streams: stream,
    }
  go h.handler()
    return h, err
}

func (bot *Handler) handler() {
    var currentPrice float64
    for {
        currentPrice = external.GetPrice(bot.Name).Price // Validated that this returns a float64
        bot.Price = currentPrice                           // Verified that this is updated immediately after in this context.
                                                       // Unable to see Price updated from outer context. 
    }
}
```

### streams.go:

```
package streams

type Streams struct {
    Trades
}

type State struct {
  Price         string `json:"p"`
  Quantity      string `json:"q"`
}

type Trades struct {
    Trades     map[float64]float64
    TradeMutex sync.Mutex
    Updates    chan State
}

func New(name string) (s Streams, err error) {
    p := newTradeStream(name)
    s = Streams{
        Trades: p,
    }
    return s, err
}

func newTradeStream(name string) (ts Trades) {
    ts = Trades{}
    ts.Trades = make(map[float64]float64, MaxDepth)
    ts.Updates = make(chan State, 500)
  // ... Other watchdog code
    return ts
}
```

Note:

I am added some debug logging in multiple locations. From within the Bot Handler, the price was printed (successfully), then updated, and then printed (successfully) again -- Showing no gap in the setting of Price from within the handler() function.

When adding the same type of debugging to the main() for{} loop, I tried setting an incrementing counter and assigning the value of thing.Price -- Printing thing.Price on each loop results in 0, even if I set the price (and validate it gets set) in the same loop, it is back to 0 on the next iteration.

This behavior is why I think that I am missing something very fundamental.

Comment: Just to start, `thing.New` returns a copy of the Handler. Once the handler is operating on the same struct, you need to add some sort of synchronization, as this will cause a data race.

Comment: Thanks, I have found the piece that I think you are referencing and removed the * which was dereferencing the original BotHandler struct. I was hoping this might resolve the issue as it sounded like the issue I was having, but same results.

Comment: No, removing that `*` changes the reciever type, so you have yet another copy. I would back up and go through some of the basics, as there are many fundemdntal issues here adding to the confusion.

Comment: Thanks @JimB for taking the time to comment. I've started at square one to make sure I did not miss anything, and I'm now seeing quite a few issues in my approach.

Answer (score 1):

In Go, arguments are passed to functions by value -- meaning **what the function gets is a copy of the value, not a reference to the variable**.  The same is true of the function receiver, and also the return list.

It's not the most elegant description, but for the sake of explanation, let's call this the "function wall."  If the value being passed one way or the other is a pointer, the function still gets a copy, but it's a copy of a memory address, and so the pointer can be used to change the value of the variable on the other side of the wall.  If it is a reference type, which uses a pointer in the implementation of the type, then again a change to the thing being pointed to can cross that wall.  But otherwise the change does not cross the wall, which is one reason so many Go functions are written to return values instead of just modifying values.

Here's a runnable example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Car struct {
    Color   string
}

func (c Car) Change() {  // c was passed by value, it's a copy
    c.Color = "Red"
}

func main() {
    ride := Car{"Blue"}
    ride.Change()
    fmt.Println(ride.Color)
}
```

Prints "Blue"

But two small changes:

```
func (c *Car) Change() {  // here
    c.Color = "Red"
}

func main() {
    ride := &Car{"Blue"}  // and here
    ride.Change()
    fmt.Println(ride.Color)
}
```

And now it prints "Red".   Struct is not a reference type.  So if you want modifications to a struct to cross the wall without using the return list to do it, use a pointer.  Of course this only applies to values being passed via argument, return list, or receiver; and not to variables that are in scope on both sides of the wall; or to modifying the underlying value behind a reference type.

See also ["Pointers Versus Values" in Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#pointers_vs_values), and ["Go Data Structures"](https://research.swtch.com/godata) by Russ Cox.

Comment: This helps me a lot. I was not aware that returns or receivers acted this way.  Thanks!